# EFCore SqlException for SelectListItem projection using same property for Value and Text

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, projection

I created a *SelectListHelper* to keep all of my dropdown data population in a central location. It projects rows in my database into collections of `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that can be consumed by my views. Here is a portion of the class:

```
public class SelectListHelper
{
    private AppDbContext _db;

    public SelectListHelper(AppDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCountries(bool showAll = false)
    {
        return _db.Set<Country>().Where(x => showAll || x.Enabled == true).OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Abbreviation, Text = x.Name }).ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetGoogleCategories(bool showAll = false)
    {
        return _db.Set<GoogleCategory>().Where(x => showAll || x.Enabled == true).OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Name, Text = x.Name }).ToList();
    }
}
```

`GetCountries`, and all other functions omitted for brevity, work just fine. They use distinct columns projected onto the `Value` and `Text` properties of the `SelectListItem`.

`GetGoogleCategories` projects the `Name` column onto both the `Value` and `Text` properties of the `SelectListItem`. This produces the following SqlException:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Invalid column name 'Value'.

When I looked at the SQL being generated by the `GetCountries` function, it looked like I expected:

```
SELECT [x].[Abbreviation] AS [Value], [x].[Name] AS [Text]
FROM [Countries] AS [x]
WHERE [x].[Enabled] = 1
ORDER BY [Text]
```

However, the SQL generated by the `GetGoogleCategories` function did not look like I expected:

```
SELECT [x].[Name] AS [Text]
FROM [GoogleCategories] AS [x]
WHERE [x].Enabled] = 1
ORDER BY [Value]
```

I'm using EfCore 2.1.0 in Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.3). Any ideas what might be going on here? I can work around this by returning an array of Names and manually building a list of `SelectListItems`, but this has me worried about what other things in my Data Access Layer might be working improperly.

---

```
public class GoogleCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; } = true;
}

public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(2)]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; } = true;
}
```

Comment: Please include the source code for the relevant properties of `GoogleCategory` and `Country`.

Comment: @mjwills - They are simple POCOs. Added as requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a 2.1 regression bug tracked by [#12180: Invalid column name: orderby uses a column alias that does not exist](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12180).

The workaround for your particular case is to use the `SelectListItem` constructor with parameters (a feature introduced in 2.1):

```
return _db.Set<GoogleCategory>()
    .Where(x => showAll || x.Enabled == true)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem(x.Name, x.Name) })
    .ToList();
```

but of course the concerns remain.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the regression bug and the workaround example.